# ng-show not able to check null or empty string

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-show

Am trying to show the html element based on condition. Like i have to check `claim.claimToDealerCurrencyExchangeRate` is empty or null. If it is `empty` or `null` then, i dont want to display the element (label and span ).

But it is not working as expected. Label & span elements are visible even `claim.claimToDealerCurrencyExchangeRate` empty.

Please find my code below.

```
 <div id="exchange" ng-if="hasClaimGrouping('customerInvoiceOrRepairDate')" 
      ng-show="claim.claimToDealerCurrencyExchangeRate == null"
      class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-lg-3">{{'claim.view.exchangeRateApplied'|translate}}
    </label>
    <span>{{claim.claimToDealerCurrencyExchangeRate}}</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: You are already using `ng-if`, it can apply to a span as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you are using both ng-if and ng-show? I think one of them should suffice. The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an expression. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has ng-show="claim.claimToDealerCurrencyExchangeRate == null" which means the div will be visible when claim.claimToDealerCurrencyExchangeRate is null. As per your ask, your logic is wrong. Use ng-hide="claim.claimToDealerCurrencyExchangeRate == null" or ng-show="claim.claimToDealerCurrencyExchangeRate != null". But since you are already using ng-if, you should combine all the conditions within it, unless you absolutely want the DOM element to be toggled between visibility and non-visibility multiple times and not have it re-instantiated every time, use a combination of ng-if and ng-show.
Also, understand empty and null are two different things in JavaScript. For example, if value is a variable. Then value = "" is empty but not null. value = "null" is not null but a non-empty string. Set value = null explicitly then it is null. And in all cases value is not undefined. Check what exactly claim.claimToDealerCurrencyExchangeRate is being set and define your logic in ng-show appropriately.